# Why does JPopupMenu take 2 passes of UIThread before rendering?

Tags: java, jpopupmenu

The first pass appears to either invalidate the drawable area or draws the background. And the second pass renders the menu. If there is any delay (as the example below exaserbates) then you get a grey square flickering effect.

This is JDK8 on Linux.

[image]

How can I stop this flicker effect?

```
public class MenuTester {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100,  100,  300,  200);


    final JButton button = new JButton("Show Menu");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("aaaa"));
            popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("bbbb"));
            popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("cccc"));
            popupMenu.setLocation(100, 100);
            popupMenu.setVisible(true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Leave enough time to clearly see the ?invalidated/background? area.
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Nothing to do
            }
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Hide after 1 second
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        // Nothing to do
                    }
                    popupMenu.setVisible(false);
                }
             });
         }
    });

    frame.add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to start by reading through [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) - Swing is SINGLE threaded and NOT thread safe. Performing long running or blocking operations in Swing will cause it to "hang" until they are completed - so you `Thread.sleep` operations are the primary cause of the issues

Comment: It should also be noted that there is also a delay between any window become visible/realised on the screen and Swing been able to render to it,  I assume this has to do with setting up the rendering pipeline for the native peer, but that's observational. I've seen some people first show the window offscreen and then move it to the active screen, but I don't know if that's particularly useful and given the multi screen state, finding somewhere off screen can be more work then it's worth

Comment: I'm well aware of Swing's threading model. The sleeps in the example code are there to demonstrate the behaviour seen in a real life app that is not blocking the UIThread.

Comment: Note also, I have been unable to replicate this behaviour with any other descendent of JComponent.

Comment: I bet you can make it occur with any window based class

Comment: You would think so, but I couldn't any others.

Comment: This kind of "delay" occurs all the time for me simply using a `JFrame`

Comment: JFrame is one of the components that I tried and cannot replicate it with. I just swapped out the code showing the JPopupMenu with code showing a JFrame. The JFrame always displays fully rendered in the first pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing has, for as long as I remember it, had a "delay" when showing windows, this might have do with the time between the frame been realised by the OS and connection of the native message and event queues, but this is pure observation

I took you code and by simply by wrapping the frame's creation into a `EventQueue.invokeLater` was able to get a similar behaviour

[image: Delayed Startup]

You will get different results on different systems depending on there system up and configurations

> What is the event that causes the window to be rendered in the first pass?

All I did was took your code and wrapped the creation the UI in an `EventQueue.invokeLater`, for example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MenuTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MenuTester();
    }

    public MenuTester() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 200);

                final JButton button = new JButton("Show Menu");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("aaaa"));
                        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("bbbb"));
                        popupMenu.add(new JMenuItem("cccc"));
                        popupMenu.setLocation(100, 100);
                        popupMenu.setVisible(true);
//                        try {
//                            Thread.sleep(2000); // Leave enough time to clearly see the ?invalidated/background? area.
//                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                            // Nothing to do
//                        }
//                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//                            @Override
//                            public void run() {
//                                // Hide after 1 second
//                                try {
//                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
//                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                                    // Nothing to do
//                                }
//                                popupMenu.setVisible(false);
//                            }
//                        });
                    }
                });
                frame.add(button);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> And is there a way to render the window as transparent during that first pass and opaque during the 2nd?

This is not a new problem, this has been the state of affair since I started with Swing at Java 1.3.  What you're asking would mean you knew when the paint pass was done AND was complete.  Swing isn't altogether stupid, it can make some clever decisions in order to optimise the rendering process (like not painting components which are visible)

The other problem is, with a `JPopupMenu`, you don't actually know if it's been displayed in a window or not (or just been displayed as a component on the glass pane for example) so the whole thing is woefully complicated

Comment: What is the event that causes the window to be rendered in the first pass? And is there a way to render the window as transparent during that first pass and opaque during the 2nd?

Comment: Sorry, my first follow up question was not clear. What is the event within the Swing rendering mechanism that is causing the window to be drawn in the first pass?

Comment: Alternatively, is it possible to have the menu initially rendered with a transparent background and then make it opaque at some later time (well after it has been fully rendered)?

Comment: First, no idea, probably isn't one, the window is been shown by the OS and then it's event loop is connected to the event queue. There is probably a small period where the backing buffer is initialised and the component begins to paint - it will go through several paint cycles when it's first realised on the screen, it can be kind of messy.  As to your second question, I'd say you'd have to try and see, but again, the problem is, `JPopupMenu` doesn't expose "how" it's attached to the screen, so you're going to have to dig through it's component hierarchy and hope you don't meet your first wndo